# Vue-Resource upload file to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I am trying to send an image through a resource and recovery in a php file but I have not succeeded, this is my JS file:

```
//* AJAX *//
startAsyncNews: function(){
    if(this.sendimage){
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file",this.contentnew.imageFile );
        console.log(this.contentnew.imageFile);
    }   

    // POST /someUrl
    this.$http.post('controllers/newsController.php', { 
        data:{action : this.accion_new, data_new: this.contentnew , imgf : formdata}
    }).then(response => {
    }, response => {
        console.log("error");
    });
},
imageSelect: function($event){
    this.sendimage=true;
    this.contentnew.imageFile =$event.target.files[0];  
}
```

When I use the `console.log = console.log (this.contentnew.imageFile)`, it shows me the properties of the image correctly, that is, it is sending the file well, but when I receive it in php and I do vardump I get this object ( stdclass) # 3 (0) no properties no properties and with json_decode / encode I get it empty, also try

```
headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
```

But it generates the following error:

> Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST

Answer (score 2):

You need to add all your data in `formdata` Object using `formdata.append(key,value)` function. 
Then you simply send `formdata`

```js
formdata.append('action ',this.accion_new);
formdata.append('data_new',this.contentnew);

this.$http.post('controllers/newsController.php', { 
    data:formdata
});
// or just if i'm not mistaken
this.$http.post('controllers/newsController.php',formdata);
```

object in http request `data`.

Comment: in php var_dump get this array(0) { } object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (0) { } } object(stdClass)#2 (0) { }

Comment: Can you try the second example ? and try to dump $_FILES.

Comment: return this :(  ... array(0) {}
No properties

Comment: can you try the same thing but without any change in headers object ?

Comment: I'm not including the headers object :(

Comment: can you try this then :  `formdata, {
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
   })`; otherwise if you can switch to axios, after all vue-resource is abondoned :/ check this [article](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4)

Comment: :( curses!...Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0
array(0) { }.... itest axios

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `this.accion_new` and `this.contentnew` are, but this line:

```
this.$http.post('controllers/newsController.php', { 
    data:{action : this.accion_new, data_new: this.contentnew , imgf : formdata}
})
```

should simply be be:

```
  this.$http.post('controllers/newsController.php', formdata)
```